# CL error with MS Visual Studio 2010, what is it

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake

I am building a project with cmake using ms visual studio.  I am getting this error from MS visual studio (2010):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Targets(146,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073740777
```

I have not been able to find anything about this error (obv I've googled it), but I can't find  a description!  I also tried the error lookup tool and it didn't bring anything up.

Any idea what this error means?

Comment: Are there any pre or post build events in VS in the project properties that could be triggering this error?

Comment: Fwiw, 0xC0000417, equivalent to `STATUS_INVALID_CRUNTIME_PARAMETER`. I'm curious if the final resolution [in this chain](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/18dc2101-ea44-44e8-af2c-c6bf4869582e/visual-studio-2010-c-native-compilation-problem?forum=msbuild) works for you. Its an interesting problem.

Comment: Seeing the CL command-line might be helpful.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Thanks thats helpful, I looks like the answer was the line length?  That would make sense in this case.  Im investing that now.

Comment: @Tom, how do I get that info? This error happens on each  library in my project. Im more of a unix guy, I don't use MS often, sorry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the project generation to a different dir (much smaller path) and the error went away, and everything compiled fine.  It appears this has to do with the path length and length of the CL command.

[This Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/18dc2101-ea44-44e8-af2c-c6bf4869582e/visual-studio-2010-c-native-compilation-problem?forum=msbuild) was helpful in diagnosing the problem.
Since my original question was "what is this error?" Here is the answer courtesy of @WhozCraig

> 0xC0000417, equivalent to STATUS_INVALID_CRUNTIME_PARAMETER.